I want this. I can create a \tree, but I can't create the Node above it

I can create a \tree, but I can't create the Node above it.

if you can create the tree, please provide the code so people don't have to do it over! this also makes it much more likely you'll get answers which work with your existing approach, which is generally useful. I'm guessing the existing answer doesn't reflect what you have already, for instance (just going by the tags). please also pick relevant tags: you can't be using all of the tree packages you list for a single tree ;).

With the forest package you can create a phantom root node. Then use tier/.pgfmath=level() to align levels. Add no edge for the first branch.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=0, parent anchor=east, child anchor=west, tier/.pgfmath=level()}
[,phantom
    [A, for descendants={no edge}[B[C]]]
    [Text A
        [Text B1[Text C1][Text C2]]
        [Text B2[Text C3][Text C4]]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}


tier/.option = level would be faster.

A small variation of nice @Sandy G answer (+1):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {grow'=0,
            parent anchor=east, child anchor=west,
            tier/.option=level,
            }
[,phantom,
    [A, for tree={no edge, font=\bfseries, color=red}   
        [B
            [C]
        ]
    ]
    [Text A
        [Text B1
            [Text C1]
                [Text C2]
            ]
        [Text B2
            [Text C3]
            [Text C4]
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}

Of you not liked styles for nodes above tree, just remove their styles (, font=\bfseries, color=red),

